# Trying to compile win32 app with winelib; type errors from winelib's header files?

Tags: winapi, ubuntu-10.04, porting, wine, winelib

I would consider myself a beginner programmer, so please bear with me if am I leaving out helpful information as I might not realize it.

I am trying to port a Win32 application to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx).

All of the source files are written in visual C++, and everything was built with the Windows API. I have been trying to use winelib to compile the program from source, however I have been getting error messages such as these:

```
    shobjidl.h:13: error: 'interface' does not name a type
```

The errors are coming from winelib's header files mostly I believe. I think that these errors are furthermore responsible for some of the scope errors generated with other winelib headers, but I would like to just try to attack this one error at a time for now.

Going into this project I felt that winelib was a good solution since the application of interest was built with the windows API, but I am confused as to why I am getting type errors with the winelib's headers...

Could it be I am missing important paths in the generated Makefile (from winemaker), or that Wine was not installed correctly on my machine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely you're not including one or more winelib header files you need.  To trace a problem like this, work backwards from the first error.  Go find where "interface" is defined.  Is the file that defines it included in your program?  If not, include it.  Do the same with the other errors, one by one.  Just be warned that figuring out correct header file sets and their order of inclusion can be really difficult and frustrating sometimes.